# Error with command $python3 manage.py migrate

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-3.x

I'm new to Django and I am running Django inside a virtualenv on MacOS with python 3.6. The command $python3 manage.py migrate but I keep getting an error asking me to install mysqlclient.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File       "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 15, in <module>
import MySQLdb as Database
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_mysql.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libmysqlclient.20.dylib
Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_mysql.cpython-36m-darwin.so
Reason: image not found

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 347, in execute
django.setup()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 112, in populate
app_config.import_models()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 2, in <module>
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 114, in __new__
new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 315, in add_to_class
value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 205, in contribute_to_class
self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 202, in __getitem__
backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 110, in load_backend
return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 20, in <module>
) from err
 django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
 Did you install mysqlclient?
```

pip3 freeze looks like this:

```
Django==2.0.1
mysqlclient==1.3.12
pytz==2017.3
```

Which other driver would I be able to use? 
I am running it in the virtual environment that I created. Also `pip install MySQL-python` doesn't work on my Mac as python 2.7 comes pre-installed and to run Django 2.0, I installed Python 3.6 and for that when I run `pip3 install MySQL-python`, I get an No Module named 'ConfigParser' error.

Comment: Did you active the virtualenv using `source env/bin/activate`

Comment: yes I activated my environment

Comment: And for which python version you have created the virtualenv ? if you're doing `pip3 install MySQL-python` means you're doing it for system's python3. If you have virtualenv setup for python3 just do `pip install MySQL-python`

Answer (score 1):

Try
pip3 install 
Instead of pip install

Since you are using python 3

And check if python3-dev is installed in your system